# Is there a command in Laravel that can create a migration, model and controller in 1 artisan command?

Tags: php, laravel

The main question is in the title already.

I am using Laravel 5.4 right now, is there something like

```
php artisan make:model Category --migrations --controller
```

and can generate :

> create_categories_table.php [migration]
>
> Category.php [model]
>
> CategoryController

Comment: I don't believe there is you can make a controller with model or a model with migration, But you can make your own custom artisan command using artisan make:command

Comment: Or `php artisan make:console commandName` depending on your Laravel version (pre-5.3 I think). See https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan#writing-commands for more info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You almost guessed the right answer. Yes, it is, you can make model + migration + controller, all in one line, using command:

`php artisan make:model --migration --controller Test`

Short version: `php artisan make:model -m -c Test`

Result:

```
Model created successfully.
Created Migration: 2017_02_27_153716_create_tests_table
Controller created successfully.
```

For additional syntax use `-h` or `--help` flag with command `make:model`, it will show all available options for this command. 
Also you can create not just an empty controller, but a resource controller with predefined CRUD methods. For that use additional flag `-r` or `--resource`.

Comment: Actually this doesn't work, i just tried it and i get an error

Answer (score 1):

There is another option and I think it's amazing, it's called: [Laravel generator from InfyOM Labs](http://labs.infyom.com/laravelgenerator/)

With a single line of code, you can generate:

- Migration
- Model
- Request

and **a lot** of others options